# Putting output of InheritanceFlags with new line character into csv file using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am working on a PowerShell script that exports all NTFS folder permissions to a CSV file. It is working fine but I want the output in a certain way and I am unable to achieve that. Here is the code:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\Test"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    $ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.FullName | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }
    foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
        $OutInfo = $Folder.FullName + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," +
                   $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," +
                   $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Currently it is generating output in this way.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KwWdX42zyX-EoMHciwSEOuSCzcQu315d

The only issue is `$ACL.InheritanceFlags` outputs two values with comma, one is **ContainerInherit** and the other **ObjectInherit**. Because of the comma the values are shifted to new cell and hence it is falling in the PropagationFlags cell.

I want the InheritanceFlags values to be in a single cell but with a line break like this.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QcZX6GmZvW2xot5hcZTMVuj4iHnzmj8Y

I tried using this `` `n `` but it doesn't change anything. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the actual type of `$ACL.InheritanceFlags`? If it's a string, you can just replace the comma with a newline: ``$ACL.InheritanceFlags.Replace(",","`n")``

Comment: Try ``$ACLs | Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$Folder.Fullname}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, IsInherited, @{n='InheritanceFlags';e={$_.InheritanceFlags -replace ',', "`r`n"}}, PropagationFlags | Export-Csv $OutFile``.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried your code but it is not generating any output in the csv file.

Comment: When you replace the inner `foreach` loop with it? I somehow doubt that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers inner line break  should be new line only `\`n` omitting carriage return `\`r`. Checked using SaveAs `csv` from _LibreOffice Calc_ (on Windows, of course).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it worked.